AWS-SDK Ошибка MalformedDate при запросе к хранилищу S3
Проект на NodeJS. Использую npm-пакет aws-sdk для соединения с s3 хранилищем.
Код:
const AWS = require ("aws-sdk");

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        endpoint: 'http://xxx:9000',
        correctClockSkew: true,
        sslEnabled: false,
        s3ForcePathStyle: true,
        accessKeyId: "xxx",
        secretAccessKey: "xxx",
    });

const buckets = await s3.listBuckets().promise();

Любой запрос к s3 сопровождается ошибкой:
MalformedDate: Invalid date format header, expected to be in ISO8601, RFC1123 or RFC1123Z time format.
    code: 'MalformedDate',
region: null,
time: 2024-04-27T13:18:24.273Z,
requestId: '17CA258EFF35F658',
extendedRequestId: 'dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 400,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 87.44154951003227

ОС: Debian. Дата синхронизирована при помощи ntp.
Команда timedatectl status выдаёт следующий результат
Local time: Sat 2024-04-27 13:23:49 UTC
Universal time: Sat 2024-04-27 13:23:49 UTC
RTC time: Sat 2024-04-27 13:23:49
Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
NTP service: active
RTC in local TZ: no


обновить aws-sdk?

aws-sdk имеет последнюю версию
